# Copy Activity Data Factory V2 Collection Refrence to String type

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to load the Json file to SQL Server using Data Factory V2. Need to save the collection Reference of type array to string in SQL Server. In below figure 'Field' object consist of multiple fields. I need to store the object 'Keywords' as string type in SQL Server DB mapped to single column. I am not able to map the 'Keywords' or 'Field' to column

[image]

Comment: I have an idea that you could using data flow to create a single column with the object 'Keywords' value, then mapping to Sink column.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Keywords is the complex type how can I convert that to single column in Data Flow.

Comment: Can you please show us a piece of the keywords? And what's the expected output data look like?

Comment: sample format of Keyword is : Keywords={"A":"1","B":"2"}

Comment: did you want store this data to a database to one string column?  Sink data like column name `Keywords`, value=`{"A":"1","B":"2"}`

Comment: Yes, I need to store the Keywords as 1 column in Database

Comment: Hi @user1696555, what we can achieve is that load the whole json data to the SQL Server one column, is that you want?

Answer (score 0):

In Data Factory, we can not load the json data `keywords` array to each row for one column as json string in SQL Server.

What we can figured out is load all the json data to one row in SQL Server.

But that is an unconventional way:

1. Set the json file as Delimiter file format.
2. Set the column and row Delimiter with the character which not exist
   in file.
3. Then the json data will be considered as a json string like bellow:

[image]

The output in SQL database:
[image]